# Can I use selenium grid instead of browserstack

Tags: ui-automation, selenium-grid, webdriver-io, browserstack

Currently My organization is evaluating on using browserstack or seleium grid as browserstack is expensive
We user WebdriverIO as framework

Does anyone know steps to integrate seleniumgrid with webdriverIO and how reliable it is ? in terms of test cases execution , parallel processing and Reports

Any suggestions are welcomed

I have integrated the browserstack with my framework and it works well but now need to integrate the Selenium grid

Answer (score 0):

Actually BrowserStack is a service which utilizes grid which makes it incorrect to compare
Regarding WebdriverIO you could check it's [documentation](https://webdriver.io/docs/configurationfile/)

```
exports.config = {
   host: '<grid url>',
   port: <port>,
   path: '/wd/hub',

   capabilities: [{
    ...
   }]
}
```